# Как добавить строку в список Python

Tags: python, строки, списки

Когда я в Python хочу в список **lis** добавить строку **"Hello world!"**, 
Python добавляет строку очень странно, и в списке в итоге получается:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

Как это исправить, и добавить в строку так, чтобы список выглядел так:

```
['Hello world!']
```

Comment: Как вы добавляете строку в список? `lis.append("Hello World!")` - работает так как нужно

Comment: @MaxU, стопудов так: `lis += "Hello World!"`

Comment: @gil9red, или так: `lis.extend("Hello World!")` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Вы можете создать пустой список а потом в него добавить
lis = list()
# Добавление в конец списка
lis.append("hello world")
# Добавление в конкретное место по индексу
lis.insert(0, "hello world")
print lis  # ["hello world"]

# Вы можете назначить список уже с элементами
lis = ["hello world"]

# конкатенацией списков
lis = []
lis += ["hello world"]
# или средствами списка
lis.extend(["hello world"])
```

Comment: еще можно добавить пример с expend: `lis.extend(["Hello world!"])` / `lis += ["Hello world!"]`